# How to change the values inside a xarray with using sel

Tags: python, numpy, select, python-xarray

I have a large xarray with x and y coordinates (area south america). Further I have a small xarray which lies in the area of the large one (the coordinates are exactly the same). The variables of the large xarray should now take over the variables of the small xarray at these points (coordinates), where they overlap. This are the teo xarrays:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
```

Dimensions:      (band: 1, x: 864, y: 868)
Coordinates:

- band         (band) int64 1
- x            (x) float64 -80.65 -80.65 -80.64 ... -73.48 -73.47 -73.46
- y            (y) float64 0.8708 0.8625 0.8542 ... -6.337 -6.346 -6.354
  spatial_ref  int64 ...
  Data variables:
  band_data    (band, y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan ... 112.0 112.1 112.2

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (band: 1, x: 7080, y: 8640)
Coordinates:

- band         (band) int64 1
- x            (x) float64 -87.0 -86.99 -86.98 -86.97 ... -28.02 -28.01 -28.0
- y            (y) float64 17.0 16.99 16.98 16.97 ... -54.98 -54.99 -55.0
  spatial_ref  int64 0
  Data variables:
  band_data    (band, y, x) float64 500.0 500.0 500.0 ... 500.0 500.0 500.0

```
#array_500 is the large xarray
#e_voronoi_raster[1] is the small xarray; [1] because its a list with xarrays; 
array_500.sel(x = e_voronoi_raster[1]["x"], y= e_voronoi_raster[1]["y"], method="nearest")["band_data"].data = e_voronoi_raster[1]["band_data"].data
```

there was no error message. However, the values of e_voronoi_rastern were not taken over. array_500 has not changed. Are there alternative methods

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of assigning values in Xarray is to use `.loc` or `.where`: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing. In your case, I recommend using `.where` with a mask that represents the area where your smaller array fits in the larger array.

```
mask = (
    (ds.coords["lat"] > 20)
    & (ds.coords["lat"] < 60)
    & (ds.coords["lon"] > 220)
    & (ds.coords["lon"] < 260)
)


array_500 = xr.where(mask, e_voronoi_raster[1]["band_data"], array_500)
```

If you can come up with a toy problem, I'm happy to update my example with an example that matches your example.